# How to enable url rewriting in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to port a webapp on the Google App Engine.
I put the source file on the GAE launcher, I've created the app.yaml and other files. Now the app is running and when it performs some script to check the server compatibility for the installation it returns me the following :

```
The mod_rewrite module uses a rule-based rewriting engine, based on a PCRE regular-expression parser, to rewrite requested URLs on the fly. It must be enabled to make TAO running properly.
```

How can I enable the url rewrite in GAE?

Comment: your app.yaml will match the incoming urls and direct them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mod_rewrite on Google App Engine (or non-Apache web servers for that matter). You can use this guide to simulate it but that doesn't mean that the package you are trying to install will stop complaining.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite